# Does a statistical law exist for the phenomenon 'the more observations, the more outliers'?

Tags: correlation, normalization

The other day, I found a strong relationship between number of observations (N_obs) and amount of outliers (N_outliers) (N = 20.000, r = .77, p <.001). My colleague pointed out that this might be just 'logical', because the chance of extreme cases increases with increasing cases.

When I performed the analysis on the normalised data (N_Outliers / (n - N_Outliers), no relationship was found indeed.

Does anyone know how this phenomenon is called? Is there a statistical 'law' behind this?

Comment: How do you determine what data is an outlier?

Comment: The distribution for the overall dataset (N = 20.000) and all individual groups (20 groups) was skewed to the right . I determined the criterium for the outlier as follows: outlier > IQR + 1.5 * IQR. For the whole group, the criterium value was 10. I tagged all observations, independent of group membership, that where higher than 11 or higher as being outliers.

Comment: If you define the outliers in terms of some % of the most extreme cases, what you are basically doing, then obviously you will get more values if you have greater sample...

Comment: I agree with @Tim. It is exactly why I asked the question

Comment: @Tim, I don't think that's it. I used the IQR range of the total dataset (50% of the data lies between  y = 0 (25p) and y = 4 (75p)). Thus, the IQR range is 4. I define all observations, independent of group membership, to be outliers if they exceed the outlier criterium (IQR + IQR * 1.5 = 4 + 4 * 1.5 =) 10. This is a fixed criterium.

Comment: As an elaboration on the above: It's not that I say: I have 100 observations and I define the highest 5% as being outliers.

Comment: Fixed criterium or not, you have defined the outliers according to the value of the datapoint alone. Now, if you somehow know the true distribution of the data you could actually calculate which percentage is expected to be above the threshold. This would the probability of sampling these 'outlying' datapoints. This probability stays the same (the population distribution does not suddenly change). ...

Comment: cont'd ... As such this will result in the absolute amount of datapoints above the threshold to grow as $N$ grows. But this only occurs due to the setting of what an outlier is to be, not because these thresholds actually create some 'statistically pure' outlier boundary.

Comment: The outlier rule you're using will converge to a cut-off at a particular quantile in the limit. The number of observations above that cut-off will converge to a binomial which will tend to grow in proportion to $n$ (its expectation is $n$ times the tail area above the quantile that the outlier rule corresponds to).

Comment: Just to be nit-picky: The OP in a comment states they are using the outlier rule `> IQR + IQR * 1.5 `. I hope this is simply a typo. It should be `> Q3 + IQR*1.5` as indicated by @whuber in a comment to Tim's answer. In the OP's example, Q3 and IQR just happen to be the same number.

Comment: You have a sharp eye. It is a typo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The answer is yes, but it depends on the underlying distribution.**

Interpreting a comment by the OP, it looks like outliers are found with a boxplot-like rule: given data, set "fences" 1.5 times the IQR away from the quartiles themselves and declare any value beyond a fence to be outlying.

When the data are a random sample from a distribution $F$, we may analogously construct two fences for the distribution based on its own quartiles.  There are two cases:

1. The expected number of outliers increases with sample size when $F$ assigns positive probability to values beyond its fences.
2. The expected number of outliers decreases with sample size down to zero when $F$ assigns zero probability to values beyond its fences.

The argument (although mathematically a little delicate to develop in full generality) should be clear.  Consider case (1).  As the sample size increases, at least one of the data fences will tend to be within the corresponding distribution fence.  In such cases, because there is positive probability of obtaining data beyond the fence and the expected number of such data beyond the fence will be proportional to that probability and the sample size, the number of data outliers increases with sample size.  In case (2), eventually the data fences tend with high probability to lie within the range of the distribution and there are *no* outlying data values (with higher and higher probability).

**Simulations illustrate these cases.**

[image: Figure]

For sample sizes $n$ ranging from $4$ through $1000$, datasets were drawn 400 times independently from a Cauchy, Normal, and Uniform distribution; outliers were identified; and the mean proportion of such outliers was recorded and plotted in this figure.  The thick white horizontal lines show the limiting values for large $n$.

- The proportion of outliers from a Cauchy distribution increases with $n$, reaching the limiting proportion for the Cauchy distribution (equal to about $15.6\%$).
- The proportion of outliers from a Normal distribution decreases with $n$, but settles to a nonzero limit (equal to about $0.7\%$).
- The proportion of outliers from a Uniform distribution decreases with $n$ and settles rapidly to zero.

Since the *numbers* of outliers are directly proportional to sample sizes, and their proportions all approach limits, we infer that the *numbers* of outliers increase with $n$ in the first two cases but decrease with $n$ down to $0$ in the last case.  This plot of the counts (on log-log axes) bears out this conclusion.

[image: Figure 2]

---

Simulation code follows.

```R
#
# Return the proportion of outliers in a data set `x`.
#
outlier.proportion <- function(x) {
  quartiles <- quantile(x, c(1/4, 3/4))
  step <- 1.5 * diff(quartiles)
  fences <- quartiles + step * c(-1,1)
  outliers <- x < fences[1] | x > fences[2]
  mean(outliers)
}
#
# Return the proportion of outliers for a distribution given by its
# CDF `pf` and inverse CDF `qf`.
#
outlier.proportion.distribution <- function(pf, qf) {
  mapply(function(pf, qf) {
    quartiles <- qf(c(1/4, 3/4))
    step <- 1.5 * diff(quartiles)
    fences <- quartiles + step * c(-1,1)
    pf(fences[1]) + 1 - pf(fences[2])
  }, pf, qf)
}
#
# Simulate data, compute proportions of outliers, and return the 
# mean proportions found in the simulation.
#
# `sizes` is an array of sample sizes.
# `f` generates iid values from a distribution.
#
simulate <- function(f, sizes, n.sim=1e2) {
  sapply(sizes, function(n) mean(replicate(n.sim, outlier.proportion(f(n)))))
}
#
# Conduct the simulations.
#
n <- ceiling(10^seq(1/2, 3, by=1/2))
n.sim <- 4e2
set.seed(17)
p.uniform <- simulate(runif, n, n.sim)
p.normal <- simulate(rnorm, n, n.sim)
p.t <- simulate(function(n) rt(n, 1), n, n.sim)
#
# Plot the results.
#
X <- data.frame(n = rep(n, 3),
                Proportion = c(p.uniform, p.normal, p.t),
                Distribution = rep(c("Uniform", "Normal", "Cauchy"), each=length(n)))
Fences <- data.frame(Distribution = c("Uniform", "Normal", "Cauchy"),
                     xstart = rep(min(n), 3), xend = rep(max(n), 3),
                     Proportion = outlier.proportion.distribution(
                                    c(punif, pnorm, function(x) pt(x, 1)),
                                    c(qunif, qnorm, function(q) qt(q, 1))))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(X, aes(n, Proportion)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=xstart, y=Proportion, xend=xend, yend=Proportion), 
               data=Fences, size=1.5, color="White") + 
  geom_line(size=1.5, alpha=0.7) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=ordered(n)), size = 3, show.legend=FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap(~ Distribution) + 
  coord_trans(x = "log10") + 
  ylab("Mean Proportion of Outliers") + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))

ggplot(X, aes(n, log10(n*Proportion))) +
  geom_line(size=1.5, alpha=0.7) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=ordered(n)), size = 3, show.legend=FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap(~ Distribution) + 
  coord_trans(x = "log10")  + 
  ylab("log10(Mean Number of Outliers)") + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this elaborate and nuanced answer. It really enriched me in theoretical understanding :)

Answer (score 9):

Without loss of generality, if you use $X > c$, where $c$ is some constant, as a rule to pick outliers, then you are basically saying that you assume that some proportion of the values are outliers. If $X$ has a cumulative probability distribution $F$, then $\Pr(X > c) = 1 - F(c) = p$, so you assume that $100p\%$ to be outliers. Of course in your case $c$ is estimated from the data, so we are talking about estimates of the probabilities. By definition, proportion $p$ of a larger value $N$ is bigger then proportion $p$ of a smaller value $M$: $pN > pM$ if $N > M$.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for this elaborate answer Tim

Comment: Using either a fixed threshold $c$ or a data-based threshold like Q3+1.5*IQR, it is possible for the number of outliers to shrink to zero as $N$ grows.  There are many examples, but the simplest is any Bernoulli$(q)$ distribution with $1/4\lt q\lt 3/4$: the IQR becomes more and more likely to equal $1$, the threshold will likely equal $2.5$, and no data will be outliers. Thus there is no such universal "statistical law" like that asked for in the question.  The flaw in the argument in this answer is the implicit assumption that $p$ is nonzero.

Comment: @whuber good point, yet the quality of such rule for finding outliers does not seem to be the main point of the question.

Comment: The question is pretty clearly stated in the title.

Comment: @whuber: I see the argument for adaptive (data-based) thresholds, but not for a fixed threshold $c$. Can you give an example?

Comment: @Moss The case of a fixed threshold $c$ fails only for trivial reasons, when $F(c)=1$, so I shouldn't have mentioned it.  (Obviously for fixed $c$ the number of "outliers" can never decrease as additional data are collected.) My focus was on the data-based threshold because that was described by the OP in a comment to the question.

Comment: @whuber you should possibly convert your comments to answer.

Comment: OK, I have done so.  I hope that makes the comments a little clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide a possible answer to this question. To the extent that your outlier selection method remains within the support of the underlying distribution, as your sample size increases the absolute count of outliers in the sample is also likely to increase. Many real world data sets and collections of scale data should follow this pattern. As whuber mentions below, mathematical exceptions arise due to some compact distributions. Assuming that your outlier selection method consistently yields a proportion p of "outliers", repeated sampling from the same distribution would generally lead to a convergence to a proportion p defined by your outlier selection rule.

The proportion of outliers after repeated sampling would be expected to remain the same as the definition in terms of the underlying distribution that is considered to be an outlier (of course you would need an accurate distributional fit or a priori knowledge of the underlying distribution for the data to define these thresholds). You would also need an outlier selection strategy that maintained a proportion p of outliers as sample size increases.

I might consider this from the perspective of the "natural tolerance" of the underlying distribution (defined as the quantiles that contain the "middle" 99.73% of the distribution in question). For a normal distribution this is the $\pm 3 \sigma$ quantiles (any standardized sample values less than -3 or greater than 3 would be outliers assuming a normal distribution is appropriate).

For other distributions you would need to find the appropriate quantiles based on your assumption/fit of the data in question. For something like a gamma distribution (shape=1, scale=2) these cutoffs would be .002702 and 13.2155 (i.e. any value less than .0027 is an outlier and any value above 13.2155 is an outlier). Remember that the selection method for outliers is still heavily debated by statisticians and is independent of the question you posed about the count of outlier values as sample size increases.

As an aside to the question, the Pearson correlation coefficient involves specific assumptions regarding normality of both of the input variables. We would need more information about the data under investigation to assess whether it is the appropriate statistic to use or if other correlation/association statistics are more appropriate or other steps should be taken (ex. transforming the sample data using a transformation like the Box-Cox transformation or Johnson transformation).

Comment: The assertions you make in the first paragraph are not generally true, so it would be helpful to supply a rationale for them that reveals when they apply and when they do not.

Comment: Care to provide a counter-example based on your understanding of the first paragraph? This might help me clarify the first paragraph...

Comment: I gave that counterexample before you even answered, Mike--see the comment thread to Tim's answer. To elaborate a bit, common outlier screening methods are modeled after the one in the question: estimate a "fence" based on some estimate of central tendency and spread. For distributions that are compact (like uniform distributions) such estimates may allow outliers to be detected due to high variation in small samples, but for larger samples may be nearly certain to lie beyond the support of the distribution.  Thus, asymptotically the chance of detecting even one outlier goes to zero.